# Skipping lines in update query

Tags: postgresql, line

I've created an update query to update lines in the Partij table with data from the Bestel table. There's one thing missing in this query and hopefully someone can help me :)

```
update partij
set Inkprijs1 = (
  select bestel.inkoopprijs
  from bestel
  where partij.levcod= bestel.levcod
  and partij.scancode = bestel.scancode
  and bestel.devisie = 'HARDWA')
,inkprijs2 = (
  select bestel.prijs
  from bestel
  where partij.levcod= bestel.levcod
  and partij.scancode = bestel.scancode
  and bestel.devisie = 'HARDWA')
,PRIJSGRP_1 = (
  select bestel.PRIJSGRP_1
  from bestel
  where partij.levcod= bestel.levcod
  and partij.scancode = bestel.scancode
  and bestel.devisie = 'HARDWA')
,PRIJSGRP_2 = (
  select bestel.PRIJSGRP_2
  from bestel
  where partij.levcod= bestel.levcod
  and partij.scancode = bestel.scancode
  and bestel.devisie = 'HARDWA')

where devisie = 'TESTHW'
   ;
```

I want to skip lines for the Partij update function when they don't excist in the table Bestel. When there are lines in the Partij tabel (with devisie TESTHW) without matching values the shouldn't get updatet at all.

Hopefully someone can help me out! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First: get rid of the scalar subqueries:

---

```
update partij p
set Inkprijs1 = b.inkoopprijs
  , inkprijs2 = b.prijs
  , PRIJSGRP_1 = b.PRIJSGRP_1
  , PRIJSGRP_2 = b.PRIJSGRP_2
from bestel b
where p.devisie = 'TESTHW'
and b.devisie = 'HARDWA'
where p.levcod= b.levcod
and p.scancode = b.scancode
   ;
```

---

The above will only touch `party` if corresponding records in `bestel` exist.

Next, you may want to supprress idempotent updates:

---

```
update partij p
set Inkprijs1 = b.inkoopprijs
  , inkprijs2 = b.prijs
  , PRIJSGRP_1 = b.PRIJSGRP_1
  , PRIJSGRP_2 = b.PRIJSGRP_2
from bestel b
where p.devisie = 'TESTHW'
and b.devisie = 'HARDWA'
where p.levcod= b.levcod
and p.scancode = b.scancode
and (b.inkoopprijs, b.prijs,b.PRIJSGRP_1,b.PRIJSGRP_2) <> (p.Inkprijs1, p.inkprijs2, p.PRIJSGRP_1, p.PRIJSGRP_2)
   ;
```

---

Finally, you should quote the ugly ALLCAPS column names (better avoid them, they do only harm):

---

```
update partij p
set Inkprijs1 = b.inkoopprijs
  , inkprijs2 = b.prijs
  , "PRIJSGRP_1" = b."PRIJSGRP_1"
  , "PRIJSGRP_2" = b."PRIJSGRP_2"
from bestel b
where p.devisie = 'TESTHW'
and b.devisie = 'HARDWA'
where p.levcod= b.levcod
and p.scancode = b.scancode
and (b.inkoopprijs, b.prijs, b."PRIJSGRP_1",b."PRIJSGRP_2") <> (p.Inkprijs1, p.inkprijs2, p."PRIJSGRP_1", p."PRIJSGRP_2")
   ;
```